# What does the colon stand for in this equation

Tags: notation

I'm reading Cohen's translation of the Principia. In chapter 7, on page 166 he states

"In sec. 1, following prop. 1, there is a lemma, basically stating that if

a : a - b = b : b - c = c : c - d ...

then

a : b = b : c = c : d ..."

Could someone tell me what this says in words?  Specifically, I do not know how to interpret the colon in this context.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It represents a ratio.  Another way of writing it is $\frac a{a-b}=\frac c{c-d}$ and so on, with the conclusion $\frac ab = \frac cd$ and so on

Comment: With the extra convenience  that the values can include $0.$ So $x:y=a:b$ means $xb=ya$ .....In some old books you may also see this as $x:y::a:b.$

Answer (score 0):

$\dfrac{a}{a-b}=\dfrac{b}{b-c}=\cdots$.